# I am using TestRestTemplate to Test with @RequestParam value how to execute

Tags: testing, spring-boot

//how to send @RequestParam value to url

```
enter code here@ApiRestController
```

public class CityController extends BaseController{

```
    @GetMapping("/cities")

    public ResponseEntity<CitiesResponse> getAll(
            @RequestParam(value = "pageNumber", defaultValue = "1") int pageNumber,
            @RequestParam(value = "pageSize", defaultValue = "100") int pageSize,
            @RequestParam(value = "sortBy", defaultValue = "id", required = false) String sortBy,
            @RequestParam(value = "sortDirection", defaultValue = "asc", required = false) String sortDirection,
            @RequestParam(value = "search", required = false) String search) {
        return new ResponseEntity(cityService.getAll(pageNumber, pageSize, sortBy, sortDirection, search), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To easily manipulate URLs / path / params / etc., you can use Spring's UriComponentsBuilder class. It's cleaner that manually concatenating strings and it takes care of the URL encoding for you:

```
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url)
        .queryParam("pageNumber", 1)
        .queryParam("pageSize", 10)
        .queryParam("sortBy", "id")
        .queryParam("sortDirection", "desc")
        .queryParam("search", "hello search");

HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers); //Update this as per your code

HttpEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
        builder.build().encode().toUri(), 
        HttpMethod.GET, 
        entity, 
        String.class);
```

Answer (score 3):

There are different ways to test in spring boot. Check the samples below:

**First option:**
It's more like an integration test. In this case the port will be the default `8080`

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
public class DemoApplicationTests {

    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate = new TestRestTemplate();

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
        String url = "http://localhost:8080";
        URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url).path("/books")
                .queryParam("order", "asc").build().toUri();
        this.restTemplate.getForEntity(uri, Void.class);
    }

}
```

**Second option:**
Very similar to the first option but this time it will run in an **random port** which can be capture by `@LocalServerPort`

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class DemoApplicationTests {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate = new TestRestTemplate();

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
        String url = "http://localhost:" + this.port;
        URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url).path("/books")
                .queryParam("order", "asc").build().toUri();
        this.restTemplate.getForEntity(uri, Void.class);
    }

}
```

> `UriComponentsBuilder` has been used to build the uri in a very friendly way.

**Third option:**
This option doesn't involve `TestRestTemplate` but just involve the `RestController` by itself. Any dependency inside the controller should be mark with `@MockBean` in the test.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(BookRestController.class)
public class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() throws Exception {

        this.mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/books")
                .param("order", "asc"))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
    }

}
```

Comment: but in this unit test i send multi @RequestParam with value(defined) and get back to response pageNumber, pageSize, sortBy, sortDirection, search value

Comment: how send @RequestParam value without request (pojo class) ?